# inserting item after getting list from DBContext for view binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert some object after querying from the database, but during view binding, a nullreferenceexception was thrown.

In my view, i did some simple looping and binding, the only thing i observed was that, the objects queried from db had a dynamicproxy object during runtime, but the object inserted didn't had any.

```
var items = ctx.items.Take(10).ToList();
var item = new Item();
item.name = "test";

items.Insert(2, item);
return (ActionResult)PartialView("_FetchPartial", items);
```

Answer (score 0):

omg i found the problem...

in the view, i've embedded some server side values on the  tag

```
<a href="@Model[i].CreatedBy.Id">@Model[i].CreatedBy.UserName">
```

Stepping through the debugger skipped this line totally and i only manage to spot it when i move the @if(Model[i].ID != 0) check all the way at the start of the loop